# Не получается вызвать в клиенте метод веб-сервиса

Tags: php, soap, веб-служба, wsdl

Решил попробовать сделать простенький клиент-сервер с использованием SOAP и WSDL.
Все делал на локальном сервере, все файлы лежат в корне сайта.

Код сервера:

**Server.php**

```
<?php 
$quotes = array( 
  "ibm" => 98.42 
);    

function getQuote($symbol) {
  global $quotes; 
  return $quotes[$symbol]; 
} 

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer("http://client.dev/stockquote.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("getQuote");
$server->handle();
```

Код на wsdl:

**stockquote.wsdl**

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?> 
<definitions name='StockQuote' 
         targetNamespace='http://example.org/StockQuote'
         xmlns:tns=' http://example.org/StockQuote '
         xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
         xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
         xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
         xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
         xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<message name='getQuoteRequest'>
    <part name='symbol' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='getQuoteResponse'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:float'/>
</message>

<portType name='StockQuotePortType'>
    <operation name='getQuote'>
        <input message='tns:getQuoteRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:getQuoteResponse'/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name='StockQuoteBinding' type='tns:StockQuotePortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc'
    transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
    <operation name='getQuote'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#getQuote'/>
    <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </input>
    <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name='StockQuoteService'>
    <port name='StockQuotePort' binding='StockQuoteBinding'>
        <soap:address location='http://client.dev/stockquote.wsdl'/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Код клиента:

**Client.php**

```
<?php 

$client = new SoapClient("http://client.dev/stockquote.wsdl");

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
print($client->getQuote("ibm"));
```

При открытии клиента, выводит ошибку **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getQuote") is not a valid method for this service in D:\wamp\www\client.dev\client.php on line 7**

P.S. Ошибку гуглил, но никаких дельных советов так и не нашел. php_soap.dll в php.ini включен, версия php - 7.0.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с wsdl что-то не так. А в целом, по поводу SOAP, могу подкинуть вам небезызвестную цитату `Бегите глупцы!!!`

Comment: У вас указан адрес WSDL, а не адрес веб-сервиса Server.php. WSDL нужен для проверки и обнаружения протокола общения с SOAP сервером, а адрес вызова для клиента должен указывать туда где находится Server.php. Читайте документацию по SoapServer и SoapClient - вам нужно и там и там указать URI сервера (http://php.net/manual/ru/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: @rjhdby неужели все так плохо?) Я читал, что веб-сервисы современная технология, в основе которой лежит именно SOAP, думал будет полезно разобраться

Comment: @MrVAN Все плохо настолько, что в версии 1.2 решили отказаться расшифровки акронима, потому что слово `simple` в ней вызывало безудержный смех переходящий в истерику. SOAP сейчас в основном используется исключительно в кровавом энтерпрайзе, но и оттуда его пытаются выпихнуть всеми силами, заменяя, где это возможно, на REST (собственно я сам в том самом кровавом энтерпрайзе работаю и наблюдаю эту эпическую битву из первых рядов)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov может я чего-то не догоняю, но ведь в документации и написано: параметр wsdl - URI файла WSDL. И у сервера и у клиента. И в примерах ниже указывают ссылку на wsdl

Comment: @rjhdby в таком случае большое спасибо за совет, буду развивать знания в другом направлении:)

Comment: Читайте документацию - у вас WSDL не отдается в Server.php,  поэтому  - "Если в не-WSDL режиме, то должны быть установлены опции location и uri, где location - URL сервера SOAP, к которому отправляется запрос, и uri - целевое пространство имен SOAP-сервиса."

Comment: @DanielProtopopov так, понятно, а как тогда отдать wsdl в server.php? Потому что у меня задача именно через WSDL все сделать. Разбирал пример на php.su, там все именно так и написано.

Comment: А зачем? Можно и так, для этого и есть возможность разделения путей WSDL и обработки запросов. Обычно WSDL файл выдается в пути обработки если в URL передается параметр ?wsdl, т.е в Server.php вы проверяете на присутствие этого параметры и делаете обычный echo содержимого WSDL файла.